# Generate scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib

I executed almost all the lines of code mentioned in this article.

https://rubikscode.net/2020/11/09/ml-optimization-pt-3-hyperparameter-optimization-with-python/

But I did not understand how the charts are generated from the model.

```
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, ls="none", marker=".", ms=12)
```

I tried this plot method and it generates the chart. But it is not anywhere close to the one shown in the article. and sns.scatterplot(X_test, y_test) returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From github:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 5))
plt.scatter(X[y == 0][:, 0], X[y == 0][:, 1], color='orange', label='Adelie')
plt.scatter(X[y == 1][:, 0], X[y == 1][:, 1], color='gray', label='Chinstrap')
plt.scatter(X[y == 2][:, 0], X[y == 2][:, 1], color='black', label='Gentoo')

plt.legend();
```

source: https://github.com/NMZivkovic/ml_optimizers_pt3_hyperparameter_optimization/blob/master/ML%20Optimization%20pt.3%20%E2%80%93%20Hyperparameter%20Optimization%20with%20Python.ipynb